# TFS 2015 and Coded UI tests - does not run

Tags: tfs, automated-tests, coded-ui-tests

I made some coded ui tests (browser based), and configured the TFS 2013 to build, deploy and execute them. 1st I execute a Test Agent Deploy step with Interactive Process [X], then executes the Run Functional Tests step with selecting the proper test suite - containing the coded ui tests. Then I deploy the test agent again without interactive process [ ] setting, then run functional tests selecting the non coded ui automated tests selecting another tests suite.

It works, for the 1st time. The coded ui tests then the automated tests were executed. But the 2nd time the test agent deploys again, then the coded ui tests starts, and seems to run endlessly. When I enter to the test agent with remote desktop  - I can see an empty console window "DTAExecutionHost" and a dialog box "Windows Security": Connectiong to TFS please provide credentials user name and password. I think this is why the coded ui tests cannot finish.

What should I do? Why it runs for the 1st time, then the 2nd time doesn't? Why it sometimes runs again?

Comment: Do you use TFS 2013? It seems you are using new build system.

Comment: It seems you're right. Version 14.102.25423.0, is it TFS 2015?

Comment: Yes, it's TFS 2015 Update 3.

Comment: Are you running the same coded UI test 2nd time as well? This popup came in my case when I was trying to make connection with tfs for the first time in any agent machine and then If  I enter credential, it does not asks me again for the credential.

Comment: In the code below it gives me same popup when I am trying to get teamproject --
_var tfs = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(new Uri("TfServerUri"));
var tcmService = tfs.GetService<ITestManagementService>();
var teamProject = tcmService.GetTeamProject("TeamProject");_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The service user has no right to connect to the TFS. It is odd, as the "normal" automated test cases were running correctly, but the coded ui ones weren't.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to run Coded UI test, you have to configure the test agent to interact with the Desktop and build agent running as interactive Mode.

Check the link below:

https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/blob/releases/m109/Tasks/DeployVisualStudioTestAgent/README.md

Comment: What do you mean "configure"? As I wrote above the Interactive process [X] parameter is checked. Do you mean I have to do something in addition that?

Comment: No, I mean the Interactive process [X] parameter. What kind of tests did you run for the 2nd time? You've mentioned they were non coded ui automated tests in the first paragraph, but in the following paragraph, you said code ui tests?

Comment: On the 2nd time "simple" automated tests are run (so called unit tests, [TestMethod] -like ones).

Comment: Are you able to reproduce this issue every time you deploy the 2nd test agent? Can you share a build log?

Comment: It does not reach the 2nd test agent, as it must be cancelled at phase 1, executing the coded ui tests, as it won't be finished. Must be manually cancelled. Now I try to reproduce the situation, but 3 times it executed well, the coded ui and the automata tests phases as well. I will share the log when it is reproduced. I'm on it...

Comment: Sorry. Our IT added right to the service user to be able to connect to TFS, and the bug seems disappeared.